# How are username, date and time are registered in kernel

Tags: kernel, proc

How is the date and time of kernel compilation registered in kernel image?

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/version 
#35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 25 17:15:33 UTC 2013
```

Comment: Where does username fit in?

Comment: And I'm sure they're hardcoded into the source by one of the build scripts.

Answer (score 1):

All this information is generated by [`scripts/mkcompile_h`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.9.7/scripts/mkcompile_h) when you run `make XXXconfig` and stored into `include/linux/compile.h`. The data is then used in [`init/version.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.9.7/init/version.c) and possibly some architecture-specific boot code to build several strings that are included in the kernel binary. There is no facility for changing them after compilation.